# [Batch ]How to remove unwanted text using CMD/PowerShell

Tags: powershell, batch-file, cmd

I've been searching for a while now for a solution to this problem:
This is the content from the beginning of the textfile `output.txt` (ofc there follow many more lines of servernames):

> ```
> Current query set
>                     name: srv-comms-xx;
>                     name: easrv00xxx;
>                     name: ealxsrv00xxx;
> ```

I would need a batch script that:

- removes the first line of this file
- removes everything from other lines except the servernames

So output of example would be:

> ```
> srv-comms-xx
> easrv00xxx
> ealxsrv00xxx
> ```

I expiremented with findstr but without success.

Comment: So the first line contains `Current query set`, right? and all the following lines start with [leading _SPACEs_ +] `name:` + _SPACE_, right? if so, use this: `> "output_new.txt" (for /F "usebackq skip=1 tokens=1,* delims=: " %I in ("output.txt") do echo %J)`

Comment: yes correct, the solution provided by Mathias R. Jessen worked for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like the previous answers, but wanted to show you an easier way available, if you can install WMF/PowerShell version 5.

This release adds a super powerful new tool called `ConvertFrom-String`. This uses FlashExtract (found in Excel) and an input example file to intelligently pull out values from any given input.

If you wanted to write some *really* succinct code, you could use this approach.  To make an input example file, just copy and paste your expected output into notepad.

```
Current query set
                name: srv-comms-xx;
                name: easrv00xxx;
                name: ealxsrv00xxx;
```

Next, note the values you want to select, (in our case, the server names).  Now, for the first few server names in the list put curly braces, the name you'd like to call this extracted value, and then a close brace at the end of what you want.  Here's an example.

```
Current query set
                    name: {name*:srv-comms-xx};
                    name: {name*:easrv00xxx};
                    name: ealxsrv00xxx;
```

Note the *, which tells ConvertFrom-String to make new objects everytime we see this value.

So, that's our example file.  Now save it somewhere (in my example T:\Example.txt), and call it using Convertfrom-String.

```
Get-Content .\output.txt | ConvertFrom-String -TemplateFile T:\example.txt
```

Output

```
name        
----        
srv-comms-xx
easrv00xxx  
ealxsrv00xxx
```

Note that we only provided two examples, but PowerShell was smart enough to recognize the pattern and extract the final server name too.  Even if our input  had thousands of names, we'd only need an example of the first three or four lines to give PowerShell enough hints as to what we want to do.

If you wanted to scrape the file and ONLY return the server names, just pipe into Select -Expand Name, like this:

```
Get-Content .\output.txt | ConvertFrom-String -TemplateFile T:\example.txt |
  Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name
```

Comment: Woah this is very very handy information. Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `-replace` operator to remove everything other than the name, using regular expressions:

```
# Read the file into an array with Get-Content
$Lines = Get-Content .\output.txt 
# Use Where-Object to filter away lines not containing "name:"
$Lines = $Lines |Where-Object {$_ -match 'name:'}
# Use -replace to capture the servername
$Names = $Lines -replace '^\s+?name:\s(\S+);\s*$','$1'
```

You can combine these statements into a single pipeline:

```
$Names = Get-Content .\output.txt |Where-Object {$_ -match 'name:'} |ForEach-Object {$_ -replace '^\s+?name:\s(\S+);\s*$','$1'}
```

Comment: Nice! this worked. Thanks. I have one more question,  I used:  `$Names | out-file -filepath hostnames.txt -append` to pipe the array to textfile. they are now just sepparted by spaces. any way to set every hostfile on different line?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a `cmd` solution:

```
for /F "usebackq skip=1 tokens=2 delims=:; " %I in ("output.txt") do echo %I
```

To write the output into a new file, say `output_new.txt`, use redirection:

```
> "output_new.txt" (for /F "usebackq skip=1 tokens=2 delims=:; " %I in ("output.txt") do echo %I)
```

To use all this in a batch script, double the `%` signs:

```
> "output_new.txt" (for /F "usebackq skip=1 tokens=2 delims=:; " %%I in ("output.txt") do echo %%I)
```

Type `for /?` in command prompt for more information about parsing text files with `for /F`.